# Explain why the empirical distribution function $F_n$ is a reasonable approximation of $F_X$ for large $n$.

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose you have a dataset $x_1, . . . , x_n$ which is a realization of a random sample from a distribution with distribution function $F_X$. Explain why the empirical distribution function $F_n$ is a reasonable approximation of $F_X$ for large $n$.

Can someone please explain or prove this sentence, I really don't know how to explain it, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Look at the Law of Large Numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to state clearly what is the empirical distribution $F_n$. This is the function $F_n\colon \mathbb R \longrightarrow [0,1]$ such that
$$F_n(t)=\frac1n\cdot \#\{k\colon x_k\le t\},$$
that is the number of observations smaller or equal than $t$ divided by the total number of observations. Note that since you can't predict the values of each $X_k$ precisely, before taking a sample the value $F_n(t)$ is a random variable (in fact, you get a different random variable for each value of $t$ considered).

The trick here is to define the variables $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n$ as
$$U_k=\left\{\begin{matrix}1& X_k\le t\\0 & X_k>t\\\end{matrix}\right.,$$
which are Bernoulli variables of parameter
$$p=P(X_k\le t)=F_X(t),$$
for every $k$; in particular, they are identically distributed and have a finite mean and variance.

Since these variables are also clearly independent, the (weak) Law of Large Numbers apply, which means that
$$\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n U_k\to E(U_k)$$
(as convergence in probability). Check out that the left hand side is actually the same as the empirical distribution at $t$, and by a property of the Bernoulli distribution, the right hand side is the actual distribution of $X$ at $t$. That is,
$$F_n(t)\to F_X(t)$$
(in probability). And this happens for any $t$. So in a sense, for bigger and bigger $n$, the empirical distribution values tend to approximate the actual distribution values, for each point $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: thank you a lot for the answer and the long explanation, now it's very clear, have a nice day!